# Create code simplier in a separate parts

Tags: html, css

```
                <input type='button' class="myButton" onclick="document.body.style.cssText+=';background-image: url(img01.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover;  background-size: cover;';" value="Sehr-Gut">
```

Is there any way to make this code simpler?  Like create a css style and put it into this onclick event?

Comment: The question should have been, is there a way to make it wrong? 
Of course! you can create a class with the styles then on javascript add this class on clicking the button

Comment: how does that make it wrong?

Comment: If this can be simplier show me how :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need JQuery for that.
Then you could use @philtune's solution or on a different approach:

```
<input type='button' class="myButton"
       onclick="$(body).addClass('some-classname')"
       value="Sehr-Gut">
```

and in your css

```
body.some-classname {
  background-image: url(img01.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### HTML

```
<input type='button' class="myButton" value="Sehr-Gut">
```

### jQuery

```
$('.myButton').click(function(){
    document.body.style.cssText+='background-image:url(img01.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover;  background-size: cover;';
});
```

## But...

An even simpler way might be to use Javascript to add a class to the `<body>` element:

### jQuery

```
$('.myButton').click(function(){ $('body').addClass('newClass'); });
```

### CSS

```
.newClass {
    background-image: url(img01.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
};
```